# Problemas com operações numéricas e NodeLists Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma função simples de somar, que pega 2 números do html, soma e deveria incluir uma div para o resultado.

```
<section class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Somando os valores 
                <p class="firstNumber">1<p>
                e valor 
                <p class="secondNumber">2<p>
            </h1>
            <h2 class="results">Resultados:  
            </h2>
        </section>

let firstNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".firstNumber");
let secondNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".secondNumber");
let resultsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".results")[0];

function createResults(text, result, className) {
    console.log("result" + result);
    const newDiv = document.createElement('p');
    newDiv.className = className;
    newDiv.textContent = text + result;
    resultsDiv.appendChild(newDiv)
}

let secondSumMethod = (x, y) => {
    return x + y
}
let secondSumMethodResult = secondSumMethod(firstNumber, secondNumber);
createResults("second sum method: ", secondSumMethodResult, secondSumMethodClassName);
```

Mas quando tento obter o resultado que no caso deveria ser um número, estou tendo o seguinte:

```
second sum method:[object NodeList][object NodeList]
```

Eu ja tentei fazer `result[0]` e também não deu certo, ai tentei criar um método

```
result = nodeToArray(result);
function nodeToArray(result) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
    return Array.from(result);
}
```

Mas ai ele retornou:

```
[,o,b,j,e,c,t, ,N,o,d,e,L,i,s,t,],[,o,b,j,e,c,t, ,N,o,d,e,L,i,s,t,]
```

O que estaria faltando no meu código?

Comment: Só lhe avisando, `document.querySelectorAll` retorna um _arraylist_ de `NodeList`, se quer "pegar" o conteúdo do primeiro elemento faça `document.querySelectorAll(".firstNumber")[0].textContent`, se quer realizar operacoes matematicas, converta de _string_ para _number_ usando o `+`:  `let firstNumber = +document.querySelectorAll(".firstNumber")[0].textContent;`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigada !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com ajuda dos comentários consegui ajustar o código.
O problema era na seleção dos números que estava ocorrendo de forma que estes ficassem em uma NodeList:

```
let firstNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".firstNumber");
let secondNumber = document.querySelectorAll(".secondNumber");
let resultsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".results")[0];
```

Com o trecho abaixo foi corrido para que o valor dos números fosse convertido para String e assim poder realizar as operações

```
let firstNumber = +document.querySelectorAll(".firstNumber")[0].textContent;
let secoundNumber = +document.querySelectorAll(".secoundNumber")[0].textContent;
let resultsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".results")[0];
```

Mais otimizado:

```
let firstNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector(".firstNumber").textContent); 
let secoundNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector(".secoundNumber").textContent);
let resultsDiv = document.querySelector(".results");
```

Obrigada !

Comment: Vale lembrar que utilizar `document.querySelectorAll` para obter somente o primeiro elemento é um _overhead_ desnecessário porque está fazendo com que o navegador busque todos os elementos para finalmente indexar somente o primeiro. Utilize `document.querySelector` para que o navegador só busque o primeiro elemento no DOM.

Comment: Eu também argumentaria que o uso de `parseInt` é mais indicado que o `+`, já que o `+` tem uma "permissividade" um pouco maior. Tem uma série de perguntas e respostas aqui no SOpt que falam sobre essas diferenças. Se tiver interesse, dê uma pesquisada, vai achar bastante informação legal. :-)

Comment: Muito obrigada pelas dicas, irei ajustar no código